# An elegant way of initialising an empty String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

In the current code base that I'm working on I find myself needing to initialise many empty String[] of different lengths.

As of now, they are always initialised in the following way:

```
String[] a = new String[]{"","","","","","","","",""} // etc...
```

Although this is a simple one line solution, my personal preference is that it's rather ugly.

I was just wondering if anyone is aware of any existing API/Utility that offers a method where an array of empty strings can be initialised more elegantly.  I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
StringUtils.*initialiseEmptyArray*(int size);
```

Does anyone know of any such method?

I can always write my own if need be, just didn't want to re-invent the wheel if its already been done.

Thanks

Answer (score 45):

You can use [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) method: -

```
Arrays.fill(a, "");
```

Answer (score 22):

Using [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
String[] a = new String[9];
Arrays.fill(a, "");
```